# Allow MongoDB remote access for specific IP

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have an application server with some PHP code on it which needs to access a distant MongoDB server.
In order to do this I want to allow remote access on my MongoDB server, but only for the application server IP.
I understand that I need to change the `bind_ip` value located in `/etc/mongodb.conf` in order to do this.
I changed it from `bind_ip=127.0.0.1` to `bind_ip=111.222.33.44` (where 111.222.33.44 is my application server IP), but it doesn't work (my PHP code says "Connection refused"). However, if I set the value to `bind_ip=0.0.0.0`, it works. Why? I don't want to let anyone try to connect on my MongoDB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind_ip` tells the `mongod` on which IP address to listen on for incoming connections. So if you set it to `127.0.0.1`, the `mongod` would only listen on localhost, and – vice versa – you could only connect when on the same machine.

When setting it to a different IP address, each host able to communicate with said IP can connect to MongoDB.

In order to make sure only your application server can talk to your MongoDB instance, you need to configure a firewall either on the server running MongoDB or somewhere in front of it.

Comment: Thx for the tips, but can you tell me why it works when I set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 but not when I set it to XXX.XXX.XX.XX?

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA `0.0.0.0` translates to "listen to all interfaces and any IP which might be assigned to it". XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX needs to be an IP associated with that machine in order to make MongoDB accessible. Again: it does not restrict the clients...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see mongodb only allow you to set a single IP for connection (or `0.0.0.0` for any IP)

What you can do to secure your mongo instance is to use firewall like [iptables](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/) to only allow specific IP's.

Run the following commands for every IP you want to allow:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 111.222.33.44 -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 111.222.33.44 -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and than to block all else (blocked some other ports used by mongodb)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27018 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27019 -j DROP
```

have a look at the [Make iptables Rules Persistent](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#make-all-iptables-rules-persistent) section of the mongo guide on how to make those rules survive reboot.